# How do I read a csv file in R with data in different cells?

Tags: r, csv

I have to read three different csv files in R to merge them later. 2 files have data stored only in the first column and all the data separated with comma. Reading and merging this files workes perfectly.
One file has data in different columns. I tried to read the file with following code:

```
events <- read.csv(
  file = "XX",
  header = TRUE,
  sep = "\t",
  na.string = "NA",
  fill = TRUE
)
```

All 3 files have headers but the headers of the file with data in different cells get all merged together to a big word.
My problem: the format of the 3 files after reading with R is different and I can´t merge them.

Is my code for reading the file wrong? How do I read a csv file in R with data in different cells?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Please show some lines from each file.

Comment: Your code to read in the file seems reasonable, but it is hard to say for sure without seeing the csv and the result. Are you expecting the headers to be the same in all three files? If so, you could import the file problematic header with `header = FALSE`?

Comment: There are no "cells" in a .csv file, only lines. The values in a single line are separated in some way. If "comma separated", the values are separated by commas. Your code indicates that the values are "tab separated". Is that the case? Other options are semicolons or just spaces. Try `readLines("XX", n=10)` to print out the first 10 lines of the file.